# Horizontal Stackpanel Fill Parent Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, stackpanel

Is it possible to have a `<StackPanel>` or labels (or buttons, whatever) going horizontally across it's parent control (e.g. `Window`) and have it fill out all the space allowed?

For example if I had 3 controls

> _ window width_***_***
>
> [ 1 ]***_*_** [ 2 ] ***_*_** [ 3 ]

or 2 controls

> _ window width_***_***
>
> [ 1 ]***_*__*_*__*_*** [ 2 ]

in each case the full width of the window is being utilized with each edge control being left and right justified respectively.

Comment: Maybe you can use a `Grid` instead? With a `Grid` this would be possible.

Comment: So you a control that will evenly space it's children horizontally? Is that correct?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A StackPanel will stack controls, so no is the short answer. That's not what a StackPanel is designed to do.

You could use a grid as Vlad suggested. Something like this:

```
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button Width="20" Height="20" Grid.Column="4"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: So then do I need to dynamically manage adding a column for each new entry and placing each control into it's own cell?

Comment: In the case of displaying a dynamic collection of items, you might want to think about using the ListBox control and set it's ItemPanel to a UniformGrid. That might get close to what you want, but I don't think you'll get the left and right justification on the first and last item.

Answer (score -6):

```
        StackPanel m_pstackpanel = (StackPanel)this.Parent;
        m_pstackpanel.Children.Clear();
        keypadclasslist keypadWindow = new keypadclasslist(m_pLstReceiver);
        m_pstackpanel.Children.Add(keypadWindow);
```